# Is it possible to write on a fifo from a exec() out?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, fifo

I have a fifo and i need to write on it the out of a exec() command. I tried using dup2(fifo,1) but it doesn't work, and i think it's because i need to invoke a write funct forcefully... So i think i'll need a temporary pipe and read from that. Is it the only way to do that?

```
int fd1[2];    
char* sed[] = {"sed","s/[^a]*//",NULL};
pipe_r = open(fifo, O_WRONLY);
pipe(fd1);
//error handling removed

pid = fork();
if (pid == 0){
    close(fd1[1]);
    dup2(fd1[0],0);
    dup2(pipe_,2);
    dup2(pipe_,1); 
    close(fd1[0]);
    execvp(sed[0],sed);
}
```

That was my attempt but the read is blocked cause nothing is written on the fifo...

Comment: What is `fd1`? What is `pipe`? What is `sed`? This is incomplete code and it is not productive to debug such code. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'll provide that in a better edit but that's not the matter, code is working well to it's purposes, i just need to redirect out and err to the pipe and that's the problem... mine was a theorical question.